# What design pattern should I use in DAL while having multiple database sources with different models?

Tags: c#, sql, .net-core, design-patterns, entity-framework-core

I've an already existing SQL database that has table Car for example that looks like this

```
public class Car
{
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string AvailableColorsCommaSperated { get; set; }
}
```

Now I'm working on migrating to MongoDb so that the data could look like that

```
public class Car
{
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public List<string> Colors { get; set; }
}
```

But I've to maintain the SQL database at the same time as it will remain used for sometime even after migration.

Now in my DAL layer I had a Master interface and class that looks like Repository pattern which the interface was like that

```
public interface ICarDAL
{
    List<Car> GetAllCars();
}

public class CarDAL : ICarDAL
{
    private readonly ICarSQL carSQL;
    public CarDAL(ICarSQL carSQL)
    {
        this.carSQL = carSQL;
    }
    public List<Car> GetAllCars()
    {
        return carSQL.GetAllCars();
    }
}
```

While to implement that using the SQLContext another interface and class with implementation exists as so

```
public interface ICarSQL : ICarDAL
{
    new List<Car> GetAllCars();
}

public class CarSQL : ICarSQL
{
    private readonly DbContext dbContext; 
    public CarSQL(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        this.dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public List<Car> GetAllCars()
    {
        // Get Cars..
    }
}
```

I could have no problem of adding a seperate layer for the Mongo to inherit from the ICarDAL and implement the functions on its own, but the problem is that I will have different Car Model for each one of them (the Car is just an example)

How can I abstract the DAL layer so that I can make the CRUD operations with different Models to different Databases? and am I going to need different context or use the same one with a factory to distinguish between different databases classes?

Answer (score 0):

you can make your interface more generic

```
 public interface IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
        T GetById(object id);
        void Insert(T obj);
        void Update(T obj);
        void Delete(object id);
        void Save();
    }
```

so each dal layer will implement it's own version
you can even use a different type for an ID
for example:

```
 public interface IGenericRepository<T,K> where T : class
    {
        IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
        T GetById(K id);
        void Insert(T obj);
        void Update(T obj);
        void Delete(K id);
        void Save();
    }
```